# UNIX folder is full(df -kh shows 100%) but won't show any big files

Tags: unix

When given **df -k /foldername**, it shows used% as 100% in an UNIX folder but inside the /foldername when given **ls -lbh**, there are no bigger files inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: UNIX filesystems have an interesting feature: a process can open a file, then the same process (or another one) can "delete" the file.  As long as the original process holds the file open, it uses disk space. It cannot be seen in the directory because unlink(), rm, or remove() clobbered it in the directory.

It will be fully deleted if and only if all processes that have the file open, close the file descriptor.  (Or the process/processes exit).

If you cannot use find to locate really big new files (this find works on almost any UNIX:

```
find /path/to/mountpoint -mtime -1 -size +10000 -exec ls -l  {} \;
```

Then you will have to try `fuser` or `lsof` - whichever tool you have.  Linux has `lsof`, most older UNIX implementations have `fuser`.

There is also a remote possibility - you mounted another filesystem on top of a directory (on your current filesystem) that already had big files in it.  It is possible to do this, almost always by accident.  I do not know how to deal with that without `umount` -ing the filesystem.  The files in the covered up directory are literally invisible AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

`df` tells you the usage of a *filesystem*, not a folder.  You can specify the filesystem by the name of any file or folder on the filesystem, but the numbers printed refer to the filesystem as a whole, not the folder or file specified.

So its likely that the large files using up all the space are in some other folder on the same filesystem

Comment: ⁺¹, a good catch. I threw away the thought because in the examples the author uses a directory name starting with slash `/`, so it is a root. But it could be an error, like `df` usage was; well, will see.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably wanted `du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h` — to print all files starting from the current directory recursively and sort it by size. The problem is likely that the big files are in hidden directories that starts with dot, like `.config`. You may see at these with `ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for tracking down filesystem utilization is ncdu.

http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu